# How to show updated data with Rails and Websocket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, websocket

For a project, I have a background task who converts thousands of photos.
I would like to automatically update the front page to brief my client of the advancement of the conversion.

I know I have to use WebSocket, but I don't know how to implement it with only one and unique Rails server.

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to use Server Sent Events. Check out ActionController::Live